# Running automate cron job in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cron

My web application runs in drupal 7.
I want to run a schedule job to send emails at a specific time.

I searched a little bit and found I could do this using drupal 7 automated cron (I don't need to use actual cron).

I am new to how hooks work in drupal, but as per my understanding this is what I did

I wrote a function hook as

```
function exampleModule_cron(){
  dpm('cron ran');
}
```

inside the exampleModule.module file

Then I manually run cron from 
Home » Administration » Configuration » System >> cron

I expect  cron to call the function exampleModule_cron and see dpm('cron ran') which I do not .

Don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going in the right direction.  Drupal's cron runs in the background and the devel module's dpm() function isn't really useful in that context.  Put a call to [`watchdog()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7.x) or [`drupal_set_messgae()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7.x) into your hook_cron. Also make sure you clear all caches or load the module page after defining a new hook to make sure Drupal has noticed the addition.

Comment: yes ,I just check my mail log and it does log the email I sent using drupal_mail() but dpm doesn't work

Comment: Don't forget to set up cron job. If you rely on drupal's default cron system it's not guaranteed that cron will run and that you code will be executed. https://www.drupal.org/cron